# In how many days can A alone finish the work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A and B can do a piece of work in 40 days. After working for 10 days they are assisted by C and work is finished in 20 days more. If C does as much work as B does in 3 days, in how many days A alone can do the work?

Here is my approach, please let me know which step is wrong. As the answer is 432 days and I am getting nowhere close to it. Thank you.

My approach-
A, B and C are per day work done by each of them.
$40A + 40B = 1$
3/4th work done in remaining 20 days when assisted by C,
$20A + 20B + 20C = 3/4$
Also, it's given that,
$C = 3B$
Solving these 3 equations I am getting,
$A = 1/48$
So,
$48A = 1$
Hence, A takes 48 days to finish the whole work by himself.
But the answer is 432. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Both your method and your answer seem correct to me.  I don't know where $432$ would come from.

Comment: @saulspatz In this [link](https://brainly.in/question/3821614) they have got 432 days as the answer and I don't understand their approach.

Comment: You can see that if $A={1\over432},$ in $40$ days A does less that $10\%$ of the work, so B does over $90\%$.  So in $20$ days, B would do over $45\%$, and working with C, who works three times as fast, they could the job almost twice over, without any help from A

Comment: @saulspatz In this solution provided in this [link](https://brainly.in/question/3821614) wrong? As there are 2 solutions provided in which one got 432 days and other got 9/5 days.

Comment: The calculations at the link are incomprehensible to me.  It starts out well, but then there are just a bunch of numbers, with no explanation.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Of course it's wrong.  If A can do the work by himself in $\frac95$ days, why does it take him $40$ days when he works with B?  You can, and should, always test your solutions by plugging them into the problem and seeing if they give you the right answer.  Your does; theirs doesn't.  You are right; they are wrong.  Good work.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_a, v_b, v_c$ the velocity of $A,B,C$, so I have: 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
(v_a+v_b)\cdot 40g=T
\\ (v_a+v_b)\cdot30g+20g\cdot v_c=T
\\ 3v_b=v_c
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Where $g$ is days and $T$ is the total work. From this, I obtain:
$$30gv_a+90gv_b=T$$
And $v_b=\frac{T-40gv_a}{40}$: $$30gv_a+90\cdot\frac{T-40gv_a}{40}=T$$ So:$$v_a=\frac{-50T}{-2400g}=\frac{T}{48g}, v_b=\frac{T}{240g}, v_c=\frac{T}{80g}$$

Answer (score 0):

If the proposed answer $A=\frac{1}{432}$ is true, then $B=\frac{49}{2160}$ and $C=\frac{1}{80}$. This implies that $C=\frac{27}{49}\cdot B$. Which contradicts $C=3B$.

I don't see anything wrong with your work. I think the proposed answer is wrong and you are correct.